# react-native gradlew command fail

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compressDebugAssets'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/AntDesign.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Entypo.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/EvilIcons.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Feather.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/FontAwesome.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Fontisto.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Foundation.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Ionicons.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Octicons.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/SimpleLineIcons.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Zocial.ttf' collided

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 34s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

Answer (score 0):

Might happen with upgrading React Native version.

Try `rm -rf android/app/build` and rebuild the project.

Reference: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#troubleshooting